# Can my iBook use any PC2700 DDR-SDRAM RAM?

Tags: memory, ibook

My iBook currently has a stick of 256MB DDR PC2700 RAM installed.

I want to bump this up to a gigabyte (because programs these days take a lot of RAM to link). I was wondering if an iBook G4 can use any brand of PC2700 or only RAM made specifically for iBooks.

For example, there was a time when graphics card needed to be specially flashed to work for Apple computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need a specific ram (like any other computers).

But be sure to buy SO-DIMM ram and not DIMM.